# How to prevent execution when someone Is absent?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I'm currently working on a slack bot. The purpose is that a developer will be selected for an update everyday at 8 am. Currently I'm trying to figure out how to prevent an execution when someone is absent.

```
var result_arr = [];
function setValue (value) {
  result_arr = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)));
  return result_arr;
  
}
db.connect(function(err) {
    db.query("SELECT * FROM developers", (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        } else {
        // selected = all.map(item => item.selected);
        setValue(result);
        removeMax();
        
        }
    })
})
```

Result from result_arr

```
rows [
  { id: 5, name: 'wqeqwe', selected: 13, absent: 1 },
  { id: 7, name: 'weqe', selected: 3, absent: 1 },
  { id: 8, name: 'me', selected: 13, absent: 1 },
  { id: 9, name: 'joe', selected: 18, absent: 0 },
  { id: 10, name: 'tim', selected: 3, absent: 0 }
]
```

RemoveMax function will take out the highest selected (8) and shuffle the others (1, 3, 4, 6), then will catch a random one

```
function removeMax() {
    const max = Math.max(result_arr.map(item => item.selected));
    newArr = result_arr.filter(item => item.selected !== max)
    shufflearray = newArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*newArr.length)];
    setShuffle(shufflearray);
    hello();

}
```

This is connected with RemoveMax, but since its async I have to make it global to add it into another function.

```
var result_shuffle = [];
function setShuffle (shufflearray) {
    result_shuffle = shufflearray;
    return result_shuffle   
}
```

The shuffler has picked a random Selected.

```
result_shuffle { id: 5, name: 'wqeqwe', selected: 13, absent: 1 }
```

Coming to the question. wqeqwe is absent today, hence the execution must be called off, however, I still want someone who is NOT absent to be selected, and have the code roll again. How do I do this?

```
function hello() {
    console.log("1", result_shuffle);
    console.log("2", result_shuffle.absent);
    
    if (shufflearray.absent == 1) {
       const baddy = "urbad"

    }
    else (shufflearray) => {
        var sql = `UPDATE developers SET selected = ${result_shuffle.selected} + 1 WHERE id = ${result_shuffle.id}`;
        db.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: is this what your data really looks like? `id: 1 - name: John - selected: 1 - absent: 1`

Comment: I typed it over from my SQL database. the - I just added for spacing.

Comment: You should show what result_arr actually looks like instead.

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot to add the result_arr code, should be fixed now.

Comment: lol, let me go back and edit my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just filter it.  You're already doing that, you just need to filter it twice, once for each condition.

But first, Math.max expects a different input.  You'll need to spread that array before it will work.  And then I have just added a second filter to the newArr mapping remove everybody that's absent.

```js
const result_arr = [
  { id: 5, name: 'wqeqwe', selected: 13, absent: 1 },
  { id: 7, name: 'weqe', selected: 3, absent: 1 },
  { id: 8, name: 'me', selected: 13, absent: 1 },
  { id: 9, name: 'joe', selected: 18, absent: 0 },
  { id: 10, name: 'tim', selected: 3, absent: 0 }
];

const max = Math.max(...result_arr.map(item => item.selected));
let newArr = result_arr.filter(item => item.selected !== max)
  .filter(item => !item.absent);

console.log(newArr);
```

But you also need to filter the absent people out of the max calculation, I think, in case one of the absent people has the highest selected, so I added the absent filter there also.  Also, bear in mind that if `joe` (18) were absent and `wqeqwe` and `me` (13) were not, both `wqeqwe` and `me` would be removed, since they have the same selected.

```js
const result_arr = [
  { id: 5, name: 'wqeqwe', selected: 13, absent: 1 },
  { id: 7, name: 'weqe', selected: 3, absent: 1 },
  { id: 8, name: 'me', selected: 13, absent: 1 },
  { id: 9, name: 'joe', selected: 18, absent: 0 },
  { id: 10, name: 'tim', selected: 3, absent: 0 }
];

const max = Math.max(
  ...result_arr.filter(item => !item.absent)
  .map(item => item.selected)
);

let newArr = result_arr.filter(item => item.selected !== max)
  .filter(item => !item.absent);

console.log(newArr);
```

Then you just shuffle that filtered array with your shuffle function.

You could also combine both conditions into the first filter:

```js
const result_arr = [
  { id: 5, name: 'wqeqwe', selected: 13, absent: 1 },
  { id: 7, name: 'weqe', selected: 3, absent: 1 },
  { id: 8, name: 'me', selected: 13, absent: 1 },
  { id: 9, name: 'joe', selected: 18, absent: 0 },
  { id: 10, name: 'tim', selected: 3, absent: 0 }
];

const max = Math.max(
  ...result_arr.filter(item => !item.absent)
  .map(item => item.selected)
);

let newArr = result_arr.filter(
  item => item.selected !== max && !item.absent
);

console.log(newArr);
```